# pandas) how to use kind option in sort_values

Tags: python, pandas

Hi I want to sort dataframe by value in column
column'values are string combination with number. I want to sort by number in values by splited
So I searched some modules to pick only number from list and apply kind option in sort_values.. but It didn't work.. Without kind option, it sort by 'D1 D10 D11 D2 D3..'. I want sort 'D1 D2 D3 D4..D10 D11'
Can you help me?

`python`
     # I want to sort by D1 D2 D3 D4 D5 D10 D11...
     df[Xlabel] = ['D1','D2','D3','D4','D5','D10','D11']

```
 def atoi(text):
  return int(text) if text.isdigit() else text
 def natural_keys(text):
  return [ atoi(c) for c in re.split('(\d+)',text) ]

 # my trying but didn't work with error message like below..
 df.sort_values(by=[Xlabel], inplace=True, kind=natural_keys[list(df[Xlabel])])

 # my trying working well but it didn't sort well
 # It sort by ( D1 D10 D11 D2 D3... ) it's not my hope
 df.sort_values(by=[Xlabel], inplace=True])
```

```
#error message when trying my method
df.sort_values(by=[Xlabel], inplace=True, kind=natural_keys[list(df[Xlabel])])
TypeError: 'function' object is not subscriptable
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think here should be better use [natsort](https://pypi.org/project/natsort/) with convert column to ordered categoricals:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Xlabel':['D1','D2','D3','D4','D5','D10','D11']})

import natsort as ns

df['Xlabel'] = pd.Categorical(df['Xlabel'],
                              ordered=True,
                              categories= ns.natsorted(df['Xlabel'].unique()))
df = df.sort_values('Xlabel')
print (df)
  Xlabel
0     D1
1     D2
2     D3
3     D4
4     D5
5    D10
6    D11
```

Also I think in new version of pandas this should be possible with new parameter `key`, check [this](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/pull/27237).

Answer (score 0):

Functions are supposed to be used by parenthesis, not square brackets, try using:

```
df.sort_values(by=[Xlabel], inplace=True, kind=natural_keys(list(df[Xlabel])))
```

Comment: Thanks for answering.. I already tried.. but It didn't work below msg..

Comment: return _compile(pattern, flags).split(string, maxsplit)
TypeError: expected string or bytes-like object

Answer (score 0):

#### Update for pandas 1.1.0 [`sort_values`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/whatsnew/v1.1.0.html#sorting-with-keys) now has key parameter:

```
df.sort_values('Xlabel', key=lambda x: x.str.extract('(\d+)').squeeze().astype(int))
```

Output:

```
  Xlabel
0     D1
1     D2
2     D3
3     D4
4     D5
5    D10
6    D11
```